# Is there any option calls the api on callback against the user if user has completed signing the document in signnow?

Tags: node.js, signnow

I have a requirement to sign a contract with digital signature.

I search a lot on google and found **Signnow** which supports like that.

**Here I have a requirement like:-**

Here I am using NODE.JS.

There are many users and they have to sing a single contract document.

I would like to share a single link to everybody and once they sign I should come to know that which user has signed.

Is there any option calls the api on callback against the user if user has completed signing the document?

It should also be recorded in the **Signnow** account for future view.

Comment: Hi Pandit, I think there are some webhooks to track the users will complete there sign.

Comment: I need some help from you, regarding how to generate embedded signing url using signnow and nodejs programmatically. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reviewing the information at https://docs.signnow.com/sn/examples/#webhooks.

If you are looking for when the document gets completed then you would make this call:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://api.signnow.com//api/v2/events' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}' \
--data-raw '{
  "event": "document.complete",
  "entity_id": "{{doc_id}}",
  "action": "callback",
  "attributes": {
    "callback": "http://my-site.com",
    "use_tls_12": true,
    "docid_queryparam": true,
    "headers": {
      "string_head": "test",
      "int_head": 12,
      "bool_head": false,
      "float_head": 12.24
    }
  }
}'
```

If you use the user.document.complete as the event then the entity id is now the user_id.

for when a user completes the signing you would use:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.signnow.com/api/v2/events \
  -H 'Authorization =  Bearer {{access_token}}' \
  -H 'Content-Type = application/json' \
  -d '{
  "event": "user.document.fieldinvite.signed",
  "entity_id": "{{user_id}}",
  "action": "callback",
  "attributes": {
    "callback": "https://my.integration.com ",
    "use_tls_12": true,
    "integration_id": "Unique ID Integration System",
    "docid_queryparam": true,
    "headers": {
      "string_head": "test",
      "int_head": 12,
      "bool_head": false,
      "float_head": 12.24
    }
  }
}'
```

If you remove the user then the entity id would be the document id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webhook to get the notification when document signed or can get the document details through API method.

**Webhooks**

You can track document statuses with the Webhooks; here is the documentation:
https://docs.signnow.com/docs/signnow/7ba1160e367db-create-event-subscription

and the list of events:
https://docs.signnow.com/docs/signnow/7ba1160e367db-create-event-subscription

**API - Get Document**

you can use the GET/document call to check the status of the document:

https://docs.signnow.com/docs/signnow/0a2c8b01c93dc-get-document

In response to this request, you will find the status information like "pending" or "fulfilled" (meaning signed) for sent documents.
[image]